# Снятие галочек с других checkbox-ов по условию

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Есть три чекбокса.
Нужно сделать так, чтобы если активен первый чекбокс, то убирались галочки со второго и третьего, а если второй или третий активный - убиралась галочка с первого.

Вот что у меня получилось:

```js
$('.food_in_tour input:checkbox').change(function() {
  if ($('#eat_all').prop('checked')) {
    if ($('#not_meat').prop('checked') || $('#not_sugar').prop('checked')) {
      $('.food_in_tour input:checkbox:not(#eat_all)').prop('checked', false);
    }
  } else if ($('#not_meat').prop('checked') || $('#not_sugar').prop('checked')) {
    if ($('#eat_all').prop('checked')) {
      $('#eat_all').prop('checked', false);
     }
  }
});
```

```html
<div class="food_in_tour">
    <label class="checkbox_custom">
      <input type="checkbox" name="food" value="eat_all" id="eat_all">
      <span>Ем все</span>
    </label>
    <label class="checkbox_custom">
      <input type="checkbox" name="food" value="not_meat" id="not_meat" >
      <span>Не употребляю мясо</span>
    </label>
    <label class="checkbox_custom">
      <input type="checkbox" name="food" value="not_sugar" id="not_sugar">
      <span>Не ем сладкое</span>
    </label>
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

В чем ошибка, и как это можно реализовать?

Comment: Два if? Попробуйте вместо последнего if --> else if

Comment: А `radio` почему вас не устраивает?

Comment: @Visman я так понимаю, предполагается возможность отметить и второй, и третий пункты разом.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Нужно проверять какой checkbox был нажат, а не состояние checkbox-ов после нажатия.
Если нажали на `#eat_all`, то убираем выделение с других checkbox-ов. Если нажали на какой-то другой - убираем с `#eat_all`.
Проверку можно делать, например, с помощью ID checkbox-a:

```js
$('.food_in_tour :checkbox').change(function() {
    if (this.id == "eat_all") {
        $('.food_in_tour :checkbox:not(#eat_all)').prop("checked", false);
    }
    else {
        $("#eat_all").prop("checked", false);
     }
});
```

```html
<div class="food_in_tour">
    <label class="checkbox_custom">
      <input type="checkbox" name="food" value="eat_all" id="eat_all">
      <span>Ем все</span>
    </label>
    <label class="checkbox_custom">
      <input type="checkbox" name="food" value="not_meat" id="not_meat" >
      <span>Не употребляю мясо</span>
    </label>
    <label class="checkbox_custom">
      <input type="checkbox" name="food" value="not_sugar" id="not_sugar">
      <span>Не ем сладкое</span>
    </label>
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```